# Quotient space for the action of finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Recently, I learnt that for the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $\mathbb C^{\infty} \setminus \{0\}$, $1.z \mapsto -z$, the quotient space can be taken as the set of all $\infty \times \infty$ symmetric matrices of rank 1 and the quotient map is $z \mapsto z.z^T$. I have no clue why the quotient space is identified with this space. Any idea in this direction is highly appreciated. Is this space the limit of the quotient space $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}/\mathbb Z_2$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: I think your argument with limit is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a general approach for identifying a quotient $X/G$ with a set $Y$. You define a map $f:X\to Y$ which is surjective and satisfies $$f(x)=f(x')\Leftrightarrow\exists g\in G\quad g(x)=x'.$$ Depending on the category you work with, you may need to show that $f$ has some properties (continuity, if you work with topological spaces, or smoothness if you work with smooth manifolds etc.).

In your case, you are already given a map as above, $z\mapsto z\cdot z^T$.